# non-finite function value integrate R

Tags: r

I encountered a problem when i was trying to use the integrate function in R.

```
non-finite function value
```

i continuous getting this error message when i call the integrate function with some data. I tried to restrict the target function in range of (-1,1)
and it integrate on a finite interval(-1,1). i couldn't find any explanation for this error. has anyone encountered this kind of situation before? many thanks

function reference link as below

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/integrate.html

following is the code

```
f<-function(p,c,n,k,a,b){
Ans=p^(a-1)*(1-p)^(b-1)*(c*p)^(k)*(1-c*p)^(n-k)
if (is.finite(Ans)[1]){ 
return(Ans)
}
else if (abs(Ans)>1) {
return(1)
}
else {
return(0)
}
}



intFun<-function(c,n,k,a,b){
return(integrate(f,lower=0,upper=1,c=c,n=n,k=k,a=a,b=b,abs.tol =100)$value)
}
```

Comment: what are the values of c,n,k,a,b?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, your problem is that you have missing or `NaN` input values, which are considered non-finite.  That means that this error can be generated not only by infinite values:

```
integrate(function(x) 1 / x, lower = -1, upper = 1)
## Error in integrate(function(x) 1/x, lower = -1, upper = 1) : 
##   non-finite function value
```

but by missing ones too:

```
integrate(function(x) ifelse(x == 0, NA, x), lower = -1, upper = 1)
## Error in integrate(function(x) ifelse(x == 0, NA, x), lower = -1, upper = 1) : 
##   non-finite function value
```