# Functions for multivariate numerical integration in R

Tags: r, numerical-methods

I have been trying to evaluate a series of complicated integrals numerically. The function I have been using so far is `dblquad` from the `pracma` package but the procedure runs into difficulties. Here is an example of these difficulties (after some preliminary functions).

```
    require(pracma)

        n.dens <- function(x, y, rho){
          n.dens <- 1/(2*pi*sqrt(1-rho^2))*exp(-1/(2*(1-rho^2))*(x^2 + y^2 - 2*rho*x*y))
          return(n.dens)
        }

        bisquare.psi <- function(x, k){
          bisquarepsi <- ifelse(abs(x)<=k, (6/k^2)*x*(1-(x/k)^2)^2, 0)
          return(bisquarepsi)
        }

        e.x. <- function(x, y){
          f <- x/sqrt(2) - y/sqrt(2) 
          return(f)
        }


        weights.o <- function(x, y, rho){
          sigma <- sqrt(1-rho)
          u <- e.x.(x, y)/sigma 
          weights <- bisquare.psi(u, k = 4.685065)/u
          return(weights)
        }

        rho <- 0.9
        dblquad(function(x, y, rho) weights.o(x,y, rho)*n.dens(x, y, rho),
                xa = -Inf, xb = Inf, ya = -Inf, yb = Inf, rho = rho)
```

But what this returns is

```
Error in integrate(function(y) f(x, y), ya, yb, subdivisions = subdivs,  : 
  non-finite function value
```

I was wondering, is there another user-friendly procedure that can do the job? Please bear in mind that the limits of integration are infinite so the function needs to be able to handle that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly are the difficulties?  Can you describe in words, or give the output of your code?

Comment: Is the problem the infinite value itself or an illogical operation performed on an infinite value? This may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653672/non-finite-function-value-when-using-integrate-in-r Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159509/non-finite-function-value-integrate-r  in both cases even though the error says "non-finite" really it means a NaN created by a misspecified function.

Comment: @Hack-R The infinite values most likely but this shouldn't be a problem because the integral itself is not infinite, as simple Monte-Carlo shows.

Comment: `a<-  function(x, y, rho) weights.o(x,y, rho)*n.dens(x, y, rho)`; `a(x=-Inf,y=-Inf,rho=.9)` gives `NaN`...